# How to plot a glm model (binomial in this case) using plot in the same way as plot(lm.fit)

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, glm

I have a binary response variable called MORTALITY, and I want to regress it on the response variables EuroScoreII, SYNTAXSCORE, AGE and SEX (SEX is binary). I entered the following:

```
model.m <- glm(MORTALITY ~ EuroScoreII + SYNTAXSCORE + AGE + SEX, family = binomial)
summary(model.m)
```

My problem is that when I use the `plot(model.m, which=1)` for example, I think they are made for a normal `glm`, not for binomial ones.

Could someone please tell me what commands I can use to carry out residual diagnostics for a binomial `glm`.

Thank you very much. If you require the data to work it out yourself, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that if you use the `boot` package as follows:

Example dataset:

```
y  <- rep(c(0,1),50)
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)

df <- data.frame(y,x1,x2)
```

Run logistic regression:

```
model.m <- glm(y~x1+x2,data=df,family=binomial)
```

Run residual diagnostics and plot them:

```
library(boot)
model.m.diagnostics <- glm.diag(model.m)    #residual diagnostics
glm.diag.plots(model.m,model.m.diagnostics) #plot residual diagnostics
```

[image]

And there you have it!

And the documentation is [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/boot/html/glm.diag.plots.html) if you want to read it.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

In Zuur (2013) p.101 the following code is provided for the validation of a binomial GLM:

```
# Residual vs. fitted
E2 <- resid(model.m, type="pearson")
F2 <- fitted(model.m, type="response")
plot(x=F2, y=E2, xlab="fitted values", ylab="Pearson residuals")
abline(h=0, lty=2)

# Cook's distance
plot(cooks.distance(model.m), ylim=c(0,1), ylab="Cook distance values", type="h")

# Pearson residuals vs. continous covariate
plot(x=df$SYNTAXSCORE, y=E2, xlab="SYNTAXSCORE", ylab="Pearson residuals")
abline(h=0, lty=2)
```

Zuur et al. (2013): A beginner's Guide to GLM and GLMM with R.